# Trouble Getting Google DFP Ads to Display in jQuery-UI Tabs

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui-tabs, google-dfp

I'm having trouble displaying Google DFP ads inside of jQuery-UI tabs (loaded via ajax). I have an example here:

http://www.anecka.com/google_dfp/

As you can see, initial page load and refresh works fine, when the user switches between tabs the Google DFP ads disappear. Google Console shows my tagging is correct, and no javascript errors in the console.

I've got a method that pushes the ads:

```
function pushVerticalGoogleAd(slot, div_id) {
        googletag.cmd.push(function() { 
            googletag.defineSlot('/7085388/' + slot, [950, 80], div_id).addService(googletag.pubads());
            googletag.enableServices();
            googletag.display(div_id); 
        });
    }
```

Each tab contains a call to this method like so:

```
pushVerticalGoogleAd('homepage_top_950x80', 'ad1');
```

Now before you say that it's because I'm reusing the same div-id and I'm declaring duplicate slots, well I agree but whenever I randomize the ad div_ids on the server, it's still presenting this problem.

I know I'm probably pounding a nail with a shoe here, so anybody with Google DFP experience know where I can get a hammer? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using the refresh method... without knowing exactly what you are trying to do its hard to know if this will work for you but the below code does at least allow the ads to display with multiple clicks...

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabs.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var googletag = googletag || {};
        googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
        (function() {
        var gads = document.createElement('script');
        gads.async = true;
        gads.type = 'text/javascript';
        var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
        gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
        var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
        })();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var divs = {};
        function pushVerticalGoogleAd(slot, div_id) {
            if(div_id in divs) {
                googletag.cmd.push(function() {
                    googletag.pubads().refresh([divs[div_id]]);
                });
            } else {
                googletag.cmd.push(function() {
                    divs[div_id] = googletag.defineSlot('/7085388/' + slot, [950, 80], div_id).addService(googletag.pubads());
                    googletag.enableServices();
                    googletag.display(div_id);
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#tabs-contain').tabs();
        });
    </script>
    <div id="tabs-contain">
        <ul id="tabs">
            <li><a href="ad1.html"><span>Tab 1</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="ad2.html"><span>Tab 2</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```